# Programmatically Upload File to Wordpress Using an API

Tags: uploads, api

I believe there is a WordPress API that can be used to programmatically upload a local file from a Windows Documents Folder using any application (like C#) to upload a file to the WordPress uploads folder.

Can anybody give me an example or explain a better route to take?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has an XML-RPC interface [with it's own API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API).

You authenticate by using a standard username and password.

You can use [wp.uploadFile](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Media) to actually send it.  See also this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872216/posting-images-via-wp-uploadfile-xml-rpc).

There is a [new API under development](http://wp-api.org/).